# JPA foreign key constraint failed

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have two classes in an unidirectional OneToOne relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@IdClass(key.class)
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private String uuid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "hash", nullable = false)
    private String hash;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns ({
            @JoinColumn(table = "table1", name = "uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid"),
            @JoinColumn(table = "table1", name = "hash", referencedColumnName = "hash")})
    private B b;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class B  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "hash")
    private String hash;
}
```

The corresponding DB is

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
   `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
   `uuid` varchar(36),
   `hash` varchar(64),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT fk_constraint FOREIGN KEY (`uuid`, `hash`) REFERENCES `table1` (`uuid`, `hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`,`hash`),                
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

in my repository i have following function:

```
    @Override
    public void save(A a) {
        if (a == null) {
            return;
        }
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(em.merge(a));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

while persisting the programm throws an excepttion :
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_schema`.`table2`, CONSTRAINT `fk_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`uuid`, `hash`) REFERENCES `table1` (`uuid`, `hash)

I really don´t know why it crashes as for my understanding jpa should be perfectly fine determing the right order in which to right entries.

note the used DB is an mysql db

Comment: try removing CascadeType.ALL

Comment: I tried it but it didnt have any effect.
In the end i circumvented the bug by changing my db design and combining table a and b